# Unable to take the screenshot in viro Package

Tags: android, react-native, screenshot

I am trying to take a screenshot in the viro package https://github.com/virocommunity/viro but i am getting the following error.

````
onButtonTap = async () => {
    if (!this.state.writeAccessPermission) {
      this.requestWriteAccessPermission();
    }
    try {
      await this.ARSceneNav.sceneNavigator.takeScreenshot('kartvya', true).then(result => {
          console.log(result.url, 'urlurlurlurlurl');
          console.log(result.success, 'successsuccesssuccesssuccesssuccess');
          console.log(result.errorCode, 'errorCodeerrorCodeerrorCodeerrorCode');
        });
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error, 'errorerrorerrorerrorerror');
    }
  };

<TouchableOpacity
    style={{justifyContent: 'center'}}
    onPress={this.onButtonTap}>
    <Text>Capture</Text>
</TouchableOpacity> ```
````

Comment: Activity can have flag "secure" and you can not capture it.

Answer (score 0):

Facing this issue, ending up using [react-native-view-shot](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-view-shot). By using `react-native-view-shot` we can take screenshot from a ref that containing viroViewRef.

```
const localUri = await captureRef(viroViewRef.current, {
  format: "jpg",
  quality: 1,
  fileName: randomName,
  handleGLSurfaceViewOnAndroid: true,
});
```